# How to fill the 'Application' column in LogCat (Android-14+)

Tags: android

Starting from android sdk and Eclipse plugin 14 (Android 4.0), the LogCat view includes a column "Application". This column is empty when I write log messages, but contains the package name of my application when android system code is executed in the context of my application.

It would be neat to be able to filter by Application to get all relevant log output; but I cannot find any documentation on how to set this... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If your apk is signed try by setting android:debuggable="true" in your Manifest file, that did the trick for me.
You can find more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10074263/2508527

If your problem is only with the monitor tool and not with the Eclipse LogCat try this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974702/2508527

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think I can answer your main question.
1. In the LogCat view of Eclipse, make sure that the filters view is visible (in the top right corner of this view there is a button that shows/hides the filter pane).
2. Click the green plus sign in the filter pane.
3. Fill in the Filter Name and Application Name fields.

Actually that was too easy - my answer looks like something from eHow - so I suspect that this isn't what you meant (or maybe you had the filter pane hidden).

I would also add that the Application Name field has been there for as long as I remember - definitely prior to Android 4.0.

I can't help you with the other problem: that the 'Application Name' field/column is sometimes blank on log lines from your application.  I haven't figured out why the lines sometimes include the Application Name and sometimes don't.

So, that pretty much makes it useless to filter on that field.  Hopefully someone else can resolve that mystery.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes just clearing LogCat buffer will help..